# How to record all tasks information with Django and Celery?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

In my Django project I'm using Celery with a RabbitMQ broker for asynchronous tasks, how can I record the information of all of my tasks (e.g. created time (task appears in queue), worker consume task time, execution time, status, ...) to monitor how Celery is doing?

I know there are solutions like `Flower` but that seems to much for what I need, `django-celery-results` looks like what I want but it's missing a few information I need like task created time.

Thanks!

Comment: create a customized table and put all required field in it can be one of the solution.

Comment: @Roshan Thanks, this is exactly what I'm doing right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you often find the answer yourself after asking on SO. I settled with using [celery signals](http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#task-signals) to do all the recording I want and store the results in a database table.